# If htaccess doesn't use cookies, then how does it identify the client?

Tags: htaccess

If I log in to my site that I protected with htaccess (so it pops up for a username/pwd) then I can't see any cookies. But why? How could the server identify that I'm the one that already logged in to the htaccess protected site? Could that be that we are on a NAT'ed network, and the server will let in others with the same public IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP is stateless; cookies are used by web pages not by web servers. When your browser makes a request to such a page, it gets back an error response saying authentication is needed. Then, it'll prompt you for your user name and password, store that in memory, and then make the request again. From there on, every request that your browser makes to that domain on your behalf, it'll automatically provide the username and password.

Your browser remembers it for you.

Comment: So the user/pwd is stored in the webbrowser cache? not in cookies. OK! Thanks

Comment: It's not stored in the web browser's cache, and it's not stored in cookies. The web browser stores it separately, in memory. If you choose to have the browser save the password, it then will be saved to disk. Most web browsers provide you the option to clear remembered passwords, either in memory or on disk, independently of clearing the cache.